LilyPond: How to have automatic accidentals (flat-sharp-natural) without placing “!’ or “?” every time
Since the upgrade of the program, we need to always add “!’ or “?” when the accidental change in the song. We didn’t do that before, only occasionally, because back then the program would add accidentals (however not every time).  So, now, hundreds of the older songs are maybe missing these accidentals. I notice this, as I am opening some old files in Frescobaldi and engrave them.
Is there a code to tell Lilypond to show all accidentals in an automatic way?
The version was 2.22.0 and I updated at 2.24.0.

Can you please show a simple example?

Which lilypond version are you talking about? Ae you sure, this is not handled by convert.-ly?

As far as I’m aware of there have not been any real changes to the relevant code for many many years, some small changes at 2.20, also some at 2.16. So unless you switched from 2.18 there should not be a change. Else it is most likely something else and might be fixed by convert-ly.

Lilypond has many different styles for including or omitting accidentals automatically, as documented here. Presumably, your upgrade changed the default strategy, so you should make sure to include your preferred policy explicitly.
(But guidot is also right: if you declared the previous lilypond version in your source files, then convert-ly should have done that automatically.)
